# How to give one Button two URL?

Tags: jsp, liferay

I use Liferay portlet bundle 6.2 (Tomcat) and Liferay IDE(eclipse). I created one Liferay Plugin Project. I save some data by using Portlet Preferences in this project and I created one button its calls "Search". When I click the button search, it will go to the other jsp. But, I will, when I click this button, that its go to two other jsp's instead one jsp. How I can to that?

Can I create one button with two onclick definition or can I created two URL's with the same var definition for one button?

Is there any possible to create two URL for one button? I'm pleased for sample example.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Independent of Liferay, a single button in an HTML form can "have" only a single URL or action handler (e.g. `onclick`). That being said: Nothing keeps you from writing Javascript code that will determine which URL a form should be submitted to, update the form and "manually" (e.g. scripted) submit the form to that URL.

As I said: This is totally HTML/JS, not at all Liferay specific. And of course you can use as many `<portlet:actionURL var="url1">...</portlet:actionURL>` constructs as you like.

Comment: I think, I explained my issue not good. I think, I can with liferay show two portlets in one page? What I will do: I created 3 Liferay plugin project and I have created 2 page in Liferay. First page should show view.jsp from the first plugin portlet (first page contains one portlet), there is located the search button. Second page should contains two portlets, one is the view.jsp of the second plugin portlet and the other portlet is the view.jsp of the third plugin portlet. When I click of the search button in page one, then I will go to page two. How I can to that?

Comment: When I need writing a javascript code, can you explain this a bit?